# Smooth Div Scroll Chrome issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm using this plugin: 
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

I'm having a problem with the automatic scroll working when the page is loaded in chrome.  It automatically scrolls in Firefox, IE and Safari but I can't get it to scroll on load in Google Chrome.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a link the page I am building:
http://www.gerardtonti.com/ArtExpo/index.html

Thank you!

Gerry

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue too with Chrome, the only thing I figured out is Chrome is not thrilled about the scrolling of 1 pixel at a time with the option of autoScrollingStep=1.

So, I increased the pixels steps, and slowed down the interval. The problem is it's not exactly "Smooth" in Chrome now.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialization
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart",
            autoScrollingDirection: "endlessLoopRight",
            autoScrollingStep: 3,   // anything less than 3 in Chrome doesn't work
            autoScrollingInterval:20 // default is 10ms, increase so it looks like you want. 

        });
    });
```

Maybe tkhan will come along with better information.